# How to get user information of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, api-v2, users

I'm currently using the Stack Overflow API to get a user's information (via Stack Exchange).

Is it possible with the Stack Overflow API to get user details?

Comment: Beyond this: `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=117982&filter=!*Mg4PjfXdyMcuySE&site=stackapps&run=true` there isn't much more details you get from the users api. What kind of details are you looking for?